# Can you include a generated file to a WiX project without adding it as an existing file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, dynamically-generated

We use HEAT to build a file for our web project installer.  I want to know if there is a way that I can have the file included in the compilation, but not included in the project.

The reason I need this is I would like to not check the file in on our source control, but have it build when we build the wixproj.  Otherwise we have to hijack/checkout the file in order to reliably build the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MSBuild and a .wixproj to build your .MSI then you will need to get the output from `HEAT` to be listed in a `Compile` item in the .wixproj. If the file is not included it will not get compiled into the final .MSI.

Fortunately, MSBuild provides quite a few options to dynamically include items. For example, you could have a custom target in your .wixproj that runs `HEAT` and adds the output

```
 <Target Name='RunHeat'>
     <Exec Command='heat.exe param param param -o path\to\output.wxs' />
     <ItemGroup>
         <Compile Include='path\to\output.wxs' />
     </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

Now if you get the `RunHeat` target to run before the `Compile` target in `wix.targets` then the `Compile` item generated in `RunHeat` will be included in the `Compile` target. Given the flexibility of MSBuild there are probably a dozen other ways you could accomplish this task.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: I had left another command in there that was forcing the file to be present